# Memory allocation in JNA

Tags: java, c++, jna

I Have a multithreaded java application which invokes c++ library (.so) using JNA.

Wanted to understand how memory is created for c++ library. Will it be per thread?

Is there a way by which we can allocate separate memory for each invocation,  so that if library is not thread safe we can run multiple threads.

Comment: You could create a small executable around the c++ library and create multiple processes with that executable from your main java application.

Comment: can you point me to example of creating executable around c++ library in java?